# Flutter increase performance of large number of Positioned Widgets on screen

Tags: flutter, performance

I'm making a grid of hexagons by placing Positioned Widgets. I have them inside an Interactive Viewer Widget so I can zoom in and out and move around.

Issue I'm having however is that with a large number of them being rendered it's far too laggy. It's unusable with about 4000 rendered on screen and ideally I need 10s of thousands. And this has nothing to do with the Widget itself as it's the same when replaced with a SizedBox with a Container or Text in.

I am using an InteractiveViewer.builder and only render the Widgets on the screen, which works great and there's no lag when zoomed in with few widgets on the screen, however I need to zoom out and see more.

I've also run in release mode and it's the same. I'm running in Windows and my PC is more than capable, too capable compared to the phones this should also be able to run on.

Is there some way to increase performance, or some other way I should be doing this instead of thousands of Positioned Widgets? Or is Flutter just not suited for this?

Edit: Image. [image: Hexagon Grid]

Comment: check `CustomMultiChildLayout` or `Flow` widgets

Comment: I suggest to use `Screenshot` and use `captureFromWidget` function for capturing widgets that are not in the widget tree, then show image on `InteractiveViewer`. Don't forget to use `compute` for building widget and take screenshot to avoid UI freeze.

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak is there a way I can still use onTap on individual tiles with that? Or maybe I should make transparent tiles generate only under where the mouse is. (Edit: Don't know how that'd work for mobile) 

And I may potentially try infinite generation, I guess if I went this route I'd have to have multiple chunks of images?

Comment: @pskink I'll take a look into those too, thanks.

Comment: @TristanKing no, if you want to use onTap on individual tiles.

Comment: @pskink tried those, no difference in performance.

Comment: I think I'm going to attempt to do it with the Screenshot and captureFromWidget, generating in chunks of images. Then I'm *hoping* I can use some kind of large GestureDetector with onTap and some maths to work out what tile would be where you tapped from the x,y coordinates.

I wish it was simpler than this and Flutter could handle more Widgets though, I mean come on we have Minecraft with *millions* of cubes loaded at a time on low-end smartphones.

Comment: what kind of widgets are those thousands children? text, image, ore more complex interactive widgets like edit texts?

Comment: @pskink well they are hexagon tiles that make up the terrain of my procedurally generated map, they can have text on them, they have shadows (so they need to be ordered correctly by their z property) they need to be able to detect being clicked on, and they can change colour (which may need to happen fairly frequently).

I'll include an image in my post.

Comment: I'm thinking this many widgets on screen is not feasible with Flutter, so think saving chunks of the grid as images may be the only way. But then I've got to work out how to detect whether you're clicking on a tile based on coordinates.

And don't know how easy it'll be to update the images as frequently as they need to be updated when tiles change.

Comment: @pskink is what I said in the post what you mean? "I am using an InteractiveViewer.builder and only render the Widgets on the screen, which works great and there's no lag when zoomed in with few widgets on the screen, however I need to zoom out and see more."

If so, I've already done that, and while it works great for reducing lag by not rendering the ones not on screen, I need to show more on screen.

My idea for creating images of chunks of the grid is to load them in based on what's visible in that same way, reducing the total number of widgets on the screen to as little as 9.

Comment: @TristanKing Did you manage to fix the issue? It would be interesting to hear what you learned.

Answer (score 2):

Using a widget for each individual hexagon at that scale feels like massive overkill. If you're going to use flutter, maybe use a [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget, which allows you to draw shapes directly to a pixel grid?

You could wrap it in a [GestureDector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) and implement scrolling and zooming via that perhaps?

Comment: This is exactly the direction I have gone, I just haven't gotten around to finishing this yet. I'm drawing multiple hexagons on a CustomPaint which will be a "chunk", this runs much faster, then as I move around in the InteractiveViewer I will load in more chunks. I plan to have a gesture detector on each chunk which based on the x and y of a click/tap I'll calculate which hexagon was clicked on. An issue I foresee is shadows between chunks though, I may have to do some "stitching" of some kind.